# block access to directories, subdirectories and files in .htaccess that is NOT specified on the list

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess

OK, so pls don't kill me, I'm not an expert, yes I have read loads of comments and forums and not sure it would be possible.

I have a WordPress site that is running on litespeed. I have wordfence and ithemes installed and my firewall is turned on, yet somehow a hacker created a .tmp folder with fake png inside containing executable code. The code could not run because of wordfence, but I would like to prevent them from creating the .tmp folder in the first place.

That lead me thinking, is is possible, in my public_html .htaccess, to list my files and folders that in the root directory, and to allow, and to deny all from everything not on the list. Theoretically then they should not be able to create any new file or folder and if they do, it would deny?

Example
Folders on whitelist:
wp-includes
admin
etc.

Files on whitelist:
index.php
wp-config.php

Would look like this

```
# Deny access to files & subdirectories
Order Allow,Deny
deny from all
<Files *.*>
    deny from all
</Files>




# Allow access to files
<Files "index.php,wp-config.php">
    Allow from all
    Satisfy Any
</Files>

# Allow access to sub directories
<Files wp-includes,admin/*>
    Allow from all
    Satisfy Any
</Files>
```

As per @RavinderSingh13's request:
Allow access the these subfolders only:
wp-admin, wp-content, wp-includes

Allow access the these files only:
`.htaccess, index.html, index.php, license.txt, readme.html, wp-activate.php, wp-blog-header.php, wp-comments-post.php, wp-config.php, wp-config-sample.php, wp-cron.php, wp-links-opml.php, wp-load.php, wp-login.php, wp-mail.php, wp-settings.php, wp-signup.php, wp-trackback.php, xmlrpc.php`

Update:
This will not work as it will not deny sever side execution. A php script can be made to delete files that are not on the whitelist, and then run with a cron every 5 min. Not ideal but it works.

Comment: Welcome to SO, could you please do provide links(samples only) which you want to block access to, that will give us better picture of your question, thank you.

Comment: @RavinderSingh13 Thanks! Sure here is a picture to illustrate:
https://prnt.sc/wgp72t
Basically, I want to block access to all files and folders I did NOT create. In order to do that I want to 'whitelist' the files and folders created by myself. I know it may sound silly, but it could be a very effective way to block hackers... I can always update the list with new folders and files I create.

Comment: Could you please elaborate more on `Basically, I want to block access to all files and folders I did NOT create`? Please do add samples in text format in your question eg--> `bla_bla` in uri I needed to block etc.

Comment: @RavinderSingh13 ok, updated in question

Comment: Thanks for adding information here. For your files `index.html, index.php, license.txt, readme.html, wp-activate.php, wp-blog-header.php, wp-comments-post.php, wp-config.php, wp-config-sample.php, wp-cron.php, wp-links-opml.php, wp-load.php, wp-login.php, wp-mail.php, wp-settings.php, wp-signup.php, wp-trackback.php, xmlrpc.php` giving htaccess access to br accesed from users is NOT recommended and is considered as a security breach also. For other files could you please do let me know if these files are present only in `wp-admin, wp-content, wp-includes` folders?

Comment: @RavinderSingh13
OK, so maybe I failed to communicate what I am trying to do. I do not necessarily want to give people access to those files. But I want files that I did not add myself not to be able to execute on my installation. For that to happen, htaccess needs to know what I added right? Like a whitelist for allowing to execute on server, and if not on list then do not allow execute. Example, if someone manages to bypass my protection, and upload a folder or file, it would be awesome to deny execution from htaccesss.

Comment: So is it like you want to allow every kind of URL from your specific IP? And deny from all others? Sorry this is what I am understanding from above, thank you.